# How can I successfully unsubscribe from user notfiications (firebase, react)

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks, use-effect

my users have a collection in their `userData` document called `notifications`. I want to listen to these in realtime so you can see notifications instantly (like any social media app, facebook instagram etc).

In my app.js, I currently have this useEffect:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    //this gets the user data
    const unsubscribeUserData = async () => {
          const userData = await getUserByUserId(currentUser.uid);
          setData(userData);
    };
    //this subscribes to their notifications
  {
    /* 
    //This the unsub method
    const unsubscribe = db
      .collection("users")
      .doc(currentUser.uid)
      .collection("notifications")
      .orderBy("date", "desc")
      .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
        let tempNotifications = [];
        snapshot.forEach((notification) => {
          console.log("adding notification: ", notification);
          tempNotifications.push(notification.data());
        });
        setNotifications(tempNotifications);
      });
    */
    }
    
    //What do I do with useRef?
    const unsubscribe = useRef();
   
    if (currentUser) {
      //If there is an auth object stored in my auth context, get their data and subscribe to their notifications
      unsubscribeUserData();
      unsubscribe();
    } else {
      //If there isn't, unsub from the notifications and set data to null
      setData(null);
      unsubscribe();
    }
    return () => {
      //If they have closed the webpage, unubscribe
      unsubscribe();
    };
  }, [currentUser]);
```

Can anyone give me a hint as to how to structure this so it unsubscribes successfully when needed?

Thanks!

EDIT (I believe this works!)

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const getUserData = async () => {
      const userData = await getUserByUserId(currentUser.uid);
      setData(userData);
    };

    if (currentUser) {
      getUserData();

      return (unsubscribeRef.current = db
        .collection("users")
        .doc(currentUser.uid)
        .collection("notifications")
        .orderBy("date", "desc")
        .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
          let tempNotifications = [];
          snapshot.forEach((notification) => {
            console.log("adding notification: ", notification);
            tempNotifications.push(notification.data());
          });
          setNotifications(tempNotifications);
        }));
    } else {
      setData(null);
    }
  }, [currentUser]);
```

I believe that calling the return at the actual snapshot listener is the same as called a cleanup return, however doing it here skips the not a function error

Comment: `useEffect` hook callback can't be `async`. I don't know if this is the cause of your issue, but it certainly isn't helping you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, AH i see, very strange. How can I await the result of getUserbyUserId()? @DrewReese

Comment: You need to take that entire callback and define it in a synchronous hook callback and then invoke it. The rub here though is you still need to return a clean up function from the hook callback to unsubscribe. I would try using a React ref to hold a reference to the unsubscribe function, to be invoked in the cleanup function.

Comment: @DrewReese ok awesome thank you, ill have a look, do you mean the useRef hook?

Comment: Affirmative, `createRef` doesn't work quite the same for functional components.

Comment: @DrewReese thanks drew, although I'm a bit unsure on how to use the useRef. see my edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue is that `useEffect` hook callbacks can't be `async` functions as these implicitly return a Promise which would, by design, be interpreted as an `useEffect` hook cleanup function. This won't work.

After looking at your code for a bit it looks like getting and setting the `data` state is independent of the firebase subscription. You can minify just the asynchronous logic into an `async` function to get and set the user data and invoke that, and access the firebase collection as per normal.

Use a React ref to hold on to the `unsubscribe` callback.

I think the following implementation should get you very close to what you are looking for. (***Disclaimer**: I've not tested this code but I think it should work*)

```
const unsubscribeRef = useRef();

useEffect(() => {
  const getUserData = async () => {
    const userData = await getUserByUserId(currentUser.uid);
    setData(userData);
  };

  if (currentUser) {
    getUserData();

    unsubscribeRef.current = db
      .collection("users")
      .doc(currentUser.uid)
      .collection("notifications")
      .orderBy("date", "desc")
      .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
        let tempNotifications = [];
        snapshot.forEach((notification) => {
          console.log("adding notification: ", notification);
          tempNotifications.push(notification.data());
        });
        setNotifications(tempNotifications);
      });
  } else {
    setData(null);
  }

  return () => {
    // Unsubscribe any current subscriptions before rerender/unmount
    // Note: uses Optional Chaining operator, if this can't work for you
    // use normal null-check:
    //   unsubscribeRef.current && unsubscribeRef.current()
    unsubscribeRef?.current();
  };
}, [currentUser]);
```

Comment: Hi there, thank you for the comment! I got an error: 
TypeError: unsubscribeRef.current(...) is not a function

Comment: @squish Are you missing the Option Chaining Operator (`?.`) before the invokation? I.e. `unsubscribeRef?.current()` instead of `unsubscribeRef.current()`. If you aren't able to transpile this code then try using a conventional null check, i.e. `unsubscribeRef.current && unsubscribeRef.current()`.

Comment: I think i may have a working solution! its yours with a slight change. ill edit my post now!

Comment: @squish No worries, like I said, I wasn't able to test it but that I thought it'd get you like 99% of the way there.